# How do you add your own Oauth2 Passport strategy to a FeathersJS app?

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

Apologies in advance for what might be an obvious question/answer, but I keep scouring the docs and cannot find it.

I know FeathersJS has drop-in strategies for Facebook/Twitter/Github -- I see those in the docs. And I know you can do all sorts of customization authorization strategies.  All I am looking to do is authenticate users through a Oauth2 provider that doesnt already have a pre-packaged strategy.  I cannot find a working example that does this.

More frustratingly, when I try to follow examples/docs, I get errors coming from the feathersjs npm modules, like:

```
    <...>/node_modules/@feathersjs/authentication-oauth2/lib/index.js:96
      app.passport.use(name, new Strategy(oauth2Settings, verifier.verify.bind(verifier)));
                             ^
TypeError: Strategy is not a constructor
```

Does anyone have a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that you didn't pass a Passport oAuth2 strategy. You can set up the [general Passport oAuth2 adapter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) very similar to the [example in the documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/oauth2.html#configuration):

```
const oauth2 = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth2');
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;

app.configure(oauth2({
  name: 'custom',
  Strategy: OAuth2Strategy,
  authorizationURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorize',
  tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
  clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/example/callback"
}));
```

Comment: thank you!  i think i got confused trying to set all the URLs and client info on the strategy, not the oauth2 configuration.